# Error in a loop which prints string from last index to first index

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, while-loop

I have written this loop to print any input string from its last index to its first index on each separate line. But when I run it, technically, it does work correctly only if the string is all lowercase. It does not work correctly for uppercase strings. In both cases, either the input string is uppercase or lowercase, the following output displays with a traceback which I do not know what for:

**OUTPUT :**

```
C:\Users\CM-Ajk\PycharmProjects\Pract\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/CM-Ajk/PycharmProjects/Pract/main.py
Enter: emadd
d
d
a
m
e
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\CM-Ajk\PycharmProjects\Pract\main.py", line 166, in <module>
    print(name[i-1])
IndexError: string index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1
```

**CODE:**

```
i = 0
name = input("Enter: ")
while True:
    print(name[i-1])
    i = i-1
```

Comment: When does your `while True` loop stop…?

Comment: Also: `print(*name[::-1], sep='\n')` for the same result (sans error).

Comment: I had written it as while len(name) > i : at first, but it did not make any difference so I changed it to true.

Comment: `len(name)` is always one more than `i`. The `len` of `'emadd'` is `5` but the last valid index is `4`… You're also decrementing `i` from `0` downwards, so, yeah, `len` is always `> i`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in name[::-1]: print(i)
```

Try above instead, [::-1] returns reversed string.

Answer (score 0):

i think is better to define a condition for the name length
and start -1 on i

```
name = input("Enter: ")
i = len(name) - 1
while i > 0 :
    print(name[i])
    i = i - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor your code as below:

```
name = 'emadd'
j = len(name)-1

while j>= 0:
    print(name[j])
    j-= 1
```

Or optionally handle int with for loop like this:

```
for i in range(len(enter)-1,-1,-1):
    print(enter[i])
```

Comment: Right, got it! Thanks.